# How to update the filters from the Venia store-front like the Magento front view?

Tags: php, reactjs, graphql, magento2, venia

Good afternoon everybody,

I am kind of a rookie using magento and I need help with this:

This are the filters from Magento front View, this filters can change position changing the position attribute in the magento/admin page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51d8F.png)

this are the filters in the Venia-storefront:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E1Yt.png)

As you can see there are not in the same position. So my question is, is there any way to connect what its happening to the position in the Magento front to affect the Venia-Storefront equally?

Can anyone help me with this?

Updating a little bit:
What I tried was to extend my graphql schema to have that position value & I did it, here is a photo of the schema:

[image: graphqlSchema]

When I use the query in the graphql playground I got the attribute correctly:

[image: queryPlayground]

I got even the correct attribute in the json in venia-frontpage:

[image: webJson]

But as you can see the value is null.

If you go to the web admin page in magento, you can see that they have values in the position attribute:

[image]

Is there any way to grab that data in the admin and take it to the position value in the schema?

I have to change the resolver? what can I do to accomplish this?

here are the photos of the resolver:

[image: resolverPart1]

[image: resolverPart2]

[image: resolverPart3]